# Is there a simple way to create a local length

Tags: macros, lengths

I want to redefine `\textheight` and `\textwidth` inside a `\parbox`. `\textwidth` works pretty well so far. But the textheight-part works only with the help of a `\newlength`. Unfortunately the `\newlength` will be created globally. `\setlength` assigns it only locally.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
\def\textwidth{\linewidth}
\newlength{\mylocal}
\setlength{\mylocal}{0.99\textheight}
\edef\textheight{\mylocal}
\parbox[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}{
\framebox[\textwidth]{Text2} 
\vfill
\framebox[\textwidth]{Text3} \the\mylocal
}%inner parbox
}%outer parbox

\the\mylocal

\framebox[\textwidth]{Text4}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is no undefined-error outside, the `\parbox`. If I use `\newlength{\mylocal}` outside the `\parbox` there will be such an error.

Comment: Why would you want to redefine \textheight and \textwidth? Why do you create a length inside a parbox? This looks rather unsane.

Comment: why do you want to redefine them? `\def\textwidth{\linewidth}` makes `\textwidth` into a macro not a length register which will break almost all existing uses.

Comment: You should not screw up the register system with `\newlength` in a local setup

Comment: I got it: Simply `\setlength{\textheight}{0.98\textheight}` and `\setlength{\textwidth}{\linewidth}`. How couldn't I see it? You may recommend not to do this, but in the package I'm making, this is locally (!) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the basics. First of all, `\textwidth`, `\textheight` and `\linewidth` are `<dimen>` registers, internally defined with `\newdimen`.

If you do `\def\textwidth{\linewidth}` you are ***not*** setting `\textwidth` to the current line width, but just making `\textwidth` into a macro that will expand to `\linewidth` (the name of the internal register that stores the current line width, to be mostly used in lists).

When you do `\edef\textheight{\mylocal}`, you're doing the same: `\textheight` becomes a macro that expands to `\mylocal`.

Such (useless) redefinitions will disappear at the end of the parbox they're made in, because the parbox is surrounded by a group. The allocation of `\mylocal` won't disappear, but its value will by the same reason.

You can use `<dimen>` parameters locally, although I suggest using your own parameters (there's plenty of registers, now).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
  \setlength\textwidth{\linewidth}
  \setlength\textheight{0.99\textheight}
  \parbox[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}{
    \framebox[\textwidth]{Text2}
    \vfill
    \framebox[\textwidth]{Text3}
  }%inner parbox
}%outer parbox

\framebox[\textwidth]{Text4}

\end{document}
```

Note that you *can* assign a value to a parameter using its current value:

```
\setlength{\textheight}{0.99\textheight}
```

is perfectly legal and effective. However, it would be much better to assign your own parameters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\newlength\mgwidth \newlength\mgheight

\begin{document}

\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
  \setlength\mgwidth{\linewidth}
  \setlength\mgheight{0.99\textheight}
  \parbox[t][\mgheight]{\mgwidth}{
    \framebox[\mgwidth]{Text2}
    \vfill
    \framebox[\mgwidth]{Text3}
  }%inner parbox
}%outer parbox

\framebox[\textwidth]{Text4}

\end{document}
```